# Induction representation of the center is not irreducible

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Suppose $\varphi: Z(G) \to GL(V)$ is an irreducible representation of the center of a non-abelian group $G$. I want to show that $Ind^G_{Z(G)} \varphi$ is not irreducible. Any hints?

So far, I have consider that $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup. Moreover, the character is given by 
$$
\chi_{Ind^G_{Z(G)}} \varphi(g) = Ind^G_{Z(G)}(g) = \frac{1}{|Z(G)|} \sum_{x \in G} \dot{\chi}(x^{-1}gx). 
$$

Comment: It might be easiest to calculate the inner product of this character with itself. First, you should note that $x^{-1}gx\in Z(G)$ implies $g\in Z(G)$, which should simplify the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that's quite helpful! I'm working on the computations right now.